# Imprimir dados de uma lista que está dentro de um dicionário - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Considere o seguinte conjunto de dados: Nome + (N1, N2, N3, N4). Nome
> representa o nome de um aluno e deve ser usado como chave. Já N1, N2,
> N3, N4 representam as notas de provas desse aluno. Utilize uma
> estrutura de dicionário com listas para resolver este exercício.  As
> notas devem ser exibidas ao final do programa com uma casa decimal de
> precisão.

Eu preciso imprimir o Nome do que é recebido via input, e suas notas que também são, mas não faço ideia de como faço isso.
Queria que retornasse algo tipo:

**joaozinho 1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0**

O código está assim:

````
for i in range(1):
    nome = input('Digite o nome do aluno: ')
    n1 = float(input('Digite a primeira nota: '))
    n2 = float(input('Digite a segunda nota: '))
    n3 = float(input('Digite a terceira nota: '))
    n4 = float(input('Digite a quarta nota: '))
    alunos['Nome'].append(nome)
    alunos['N1'].append(n1)
    alunos['N2'].append(n2)
    alunos['N3'].append(n3)
    alunos['N4'].append(n4)

for nome, nota in alunos.items():
    print(nome, nota)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Analisando o código, cheguei a uma outra forma, mas ainda não consigo imprimir na tela do jeito que pede no enunciado:

```
boletim = {'nome':[], 'n1':[], 'n2':[], 'n3':[], 'n4':[]}

num = int(input('Qual o número de alunos? '))
for i in range(num):
    nome = input('Digite o nome do aluno: ')
    n1 = float(input('Digite a primeira nota: '))
    n2 = float(input('Digite a segunda nota: '))
    n3 = float(input('Digite a terceira nota: '))
    n4 = float(input('Digite a quarta nota: '))
    boletim['nome'].append(nome)
    boletim['n1'].append(n1)
    boletim['n2'].append(n2)
    boletim['n3'].append(n3)
    boletim['n4'].append(n4)
print('\nNota dos alunos')
print('-' * 90)
```

Comment: Estou movendo esse enunciado para a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esta questão você deve prestar atenção na seguinte lógica:

1. Capturar o nome da pessoa;
2. Montar uma lista com as notas da pessoa;
3. Alimentar o dicionário com nome e notas;
4. Exibir chave, valor do dicionário.

Uma das forma para se resolver tal questão é:

```
nome = input('Digite o nome: ')

nome_nota = dict()
notas = list()
for i in range(1, 5):
    notas.append(float(input(f'Digite a {i}º nota: ')))

nome_nota.update({nome: notas})

for j, k in nome_nota.items():
    print(j, *k)
```

Observe que ao executar o código devemos informar o nome da pessoa. Em seguida, devemos digitar cada uma das quatro notas para ser inseridas na lista **notas**.

**Observação:** Para adicionar valores em uma **[lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)** utilizamos o método **append()** e para adicionarmos chave/valor em dicionário utilizamos o método **update()**.

Depois que o bloco **for** inserir todos os valores na lista **notas** serão adicionados **nome e notas** ao dicionário.

Posteriormente o segundo bloco **for** irá percorrer **chave/valor** do dicionário exibindo respectivamente a chave e o valor. Como o valor é formado por elementos de uma lista devemos desempacotá-los, o que conseguimos, inserindo o sinal de (*) - asterisco - imediatamente antes da lista **notas**.

---

Existe outra forma mais concisa de resolver esta questão utilizando os conceitos de **[dictionary comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)**. Desta forma podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
nome = input('Digite o nome: ')
nome_nota = {nome: [float(input(f'Digite a {i}º nota: ')) for i in range(1, 5)]}

for j, k in nome_nota.items():
    print(j, *k)
```

Observe que neste código foi implementado um **Dictionary Comprehension**. Onde a chave corresponde à **nome** e o valor corresponde à lista montada com auxílio de **[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** no qual cada elemento é o valor da cada uma das 4 notas do aluno.